# JavaScript/jQuery interval executed twice in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, setinterval

I created a little fadeIn/fadeOut carousel in jQuery and it's working fine in every standard-compliant browser I've tested it in so far; except Internet Explorer 9.

The carousel is set to roll to the next *item* every 15000 milliseconds using `setInterval` and it also uses `window.addEventListener` to pause it when focusing out of the window.

As I was testing it in Internet Explorer 9, I noticed that every interval is executed twice each time, so instead of switching to the next item and then waiting for 15 seconds (like happens in other browsers) it rolls over two items before waiting for the next interval.

The code is probably too long to post but the page itself is located at http://www.stefanvignir.de/ and the JavaScript file is located at http://www.stefanvignir.de/carousel.js.

What can I do to make this work properly in IE9 and is there anything I should avoid when adapting JavaScript to IE?

Comment: It does just that in Firefox 5.01 as well. Might also be some ambiguous part in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that your focus listener is getting called when everything is starting up. You could try checking if you have a `carouselIntervalId` before starting the timers:

```
if(!carouselIntervalId)
    carouselIntervalId = setInterval(...);
```

And since we're all properly paranoid here, put that check before **both** `setInterval` calls.

Then you'd want to nullifying `carouselIntervalId` when you stop the timer:

```
if(carouselIntervalId)
    clearInterval(carouselIntervalId);
carouselIntervalId = null;
```

You'd want the above around all `clearInterval` calls of course.

Also, while I have your attention (?), I notice that you have two different `setInterval` calls:

```
setInterval(function() { carouselNext() }, 15000);
// And later...
setInterval(function() { if (animate == true) { carouselNext() } }, 15000);
```

You might want to make them the same to avoid confusion and bugs.

Comment: I can verify in the IE debugger that the code is setting two interval timers upon startup - one in your intialization and one in the initial focus event.  The fix would be as mu said to not set a new interval if one is already running.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks, I didn't want to drag out my IE testing gear.

Comment: checking for `carouselIntervalId` seems to have done the trick. It was somehow stuck in the back of my mind that setting a new value for `carouselIntervalId` would simply delete the old interval and replace it with a new one.